# With the new maps in iOS6, is it possible to change colors of layers (parks, water, building)

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios6, mapkit

I understand it's not ideal to change mapkit colors but specifically for a location based game I'm creating I'd like to have to colors much less dramatic and more dark. Is there a built in way that I can accomplish this? Since the game won't be specific to a certain region custom overlays wouldn't really work. I know with the old google maps the only way to do so was to create a javascript version of the map and add it in a webview (not ideal for the game) but with this new apple maps is there a way to redraw the shapes of these elements (parks, water, building) with a different color.

I don't have a complete understanding how the previous or current mapkits work from the ground up so if I'm missing any information or am confusing I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there is no way you can do that in the current iOS6 maps.

The [MapKit Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MapKit_Framework_Reference/_index.html) does not have any inbuilt functions to do that.

I would seriously ask you to reconsider changing colors of the current MapKit even if you could do it through some other hack. You might get rejected from the App Store.

You have 2 options 
a. Instead use your own maps from other vendors if you want to change colors and so for different places.

b. [Overlays](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKOverlayView_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009715) are a good way to go too but they are heavy work on REST side of downloading maps. I am currently using this in my map right now because all my map tiles are generated on the fly and I do not have to do too intensive work on the iPhone.

Comment: Thanks, I was afraid of this. I will probably just release it as is with current colors and maybe adjust my UI to complement to maps better. The overlays thing could work but I don't think it would be worth it. I was hoping there was a way to intercept the polygon and redraw the context as a different color.